# flask limiter override 429 if user not authenticated

Tags: python, flask, flask-limiter

I have the following code. The first `HTTP` request is within the threshold (`1 per day, 1 per hour`), so I get 401 on the first request.any subsequent `HTTP` request gives me 429.
I am trying to make the code work so that if a user is not authenticated, it overrides 429 and sends 401 or raises an Auth error. In my example, I assume the user is not authenticated. Since if a user is authenticated, it should get 429 once the threshold crosses.

```
from flask_limiter import Limiter
from flask_limiter.util import get_remote_address
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)
limiter = Limiter(
    app=app,
    key_func=get_remote_address,
    default_limits=["1 per day", "1 per hour"],
    storage_uri="memory://",
)

@app.before_request
def check_rate_limit():
    print('Checking rate limit')
    if is_authenticated():
        print('user is authenticated')
        resp = limiter.check()
        if resp and resp[1]:
            return jsonify({"message": "Rate limit exceeded"}), 429
    else:
        print('user not authenticated')


# Custom decorator for authentication
def authenticated_request(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not is_authenticated():
            print('not authenticated')
            return jsonify({"message": "Unauthorized"}), 401
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function


def is_authenticated():
    return False


@app.route('/example')
@authenticated_request
def example_route():
    return jsonify({"message": "This is an example route"})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using Flask-Limiter to enforce rate limiting and a custom decorator `(authenticated_request)` to check for authentication before allowing access to certain routes. However, the issue you've mentioned is that if a user is not authenticated, you're still encountering rate limit issues.

In your `check_rate_limit function`, you're calling `limiter.check()` to check the rate limit. If the user is not authenticated, you're not explicitly returning a response, so the function continues to process the request. However, you want to override the rate limit response when the user is not authenticated.

```
def is_authenticated():
    # Your authentication logic here
    return False

@app.before_request
def check_rate_limit():
    print('Checking rate limit')
    if is_authenticated():
        print('User is authenticated')
        resp = limiter.check()
        if resp and resp[1]:
            return jsonify({"message": "Rate limit exceeded"}), 429
    else:
        print('User not authenticated')
        # Override rate limit response when user is not authenticated
        return jsonify({"message": "Unauthorized"}), 401
```

Comment: Even with the modification of the code you gave. For the first HTTP call, I am getting 401 but second I am getting 429. any HTTP call should return 401 since the user is not authenticated. Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure that the rate limit check is performed after the authentication check. You can achieve this by removing the `check_rate_limit` function and incorporating the rate limit check directly into the `authenticated_request` decorator.

Comment: def authenticated_request(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        if not is_authenticated():
            print('not authenticated returning 401')
            return jsonify({"message": "Unauthorized"}), 401

        print('checking limiter check')
        # check rate limit after authentication
        resp = limiter.check()
        if resp and resp[1]:
            print('returning 429...')
            return jsonify({"message": "Rate limit exceeded"}), 429

        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated_function